Custom Plugin Breaks Other Plugin Functions
I wrote a custom plugin and when activated it breaks my ajax for wpdatatables.  I have found that it is my CSS that is breaking this.  How would I go about running the CSS code ONLY on that one page?
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Remove From Club
Description: Submit to remove.
Version: 1.0
Author: Diamond Dave    
*/



$display_name =  $current_user->display_name;



?>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php

// Create shortcode for the form
function custom_form_shortcode() {
            
    ob_start(); ?>
    <h2>Remove From Club Form</h2>
   <?php 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_name = $current_user->display_name;
    ?>
    <p>Welcome, <?php echo $user_name; ?>!</p>
   <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" width="50%" class="swag">
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleInputEmail1" name="submitname" aria-describedby="emailHelp" value="<?php echo $user_name ?> " readonly >
  </div><br />
     
       <div class="form-group col-md-12">

    <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="exampleInputPassword1" name="brothername" placeholder="Brother Name">
  </div><br />

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="clubname" placeholder="Clan Name">
  </div><br />

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="female" placeholder="Valkyrie Name (If on Roster)">
  </div><br />

  <div class="form-group col-md-12">

    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" name="status" placeholder="status" Value="Pending">
  </div><br />
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="upload">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    <?php
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('custom_form', 'custom_form_shortcode');

// Process form submission
function custom_form_submission() {
    if(isset($_POST['submitname'])){
        // Retrieve form data
        $submitname = sanitize_text_field($_POST['submitname']);
        $brothername = sanitize_text_field($_POST['brothername']);
        $female= sanitize_text_field($_POST['female']);
        $status = sanitize_text_field($_POST['status']);
        $clubname= sanitize_text_field($_POST['clubname']);
        
        // Insert data into database
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . '1_remove_brother';
        $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name,
            array(
                'submitname' => $submitname,
                'brothername' => $brothername,
                'female' => $female,
                'status' => $status,
                'clubname' => $clubname
            )
        );

        // Send email
        $to = "MYEMAILADDR";
        $subject = "Remove From Roster Submission";
        $message = "Submitter's Name: $submitname\nBrother's Name: $brothername\nValkyrie: $female\nStatus: $status\nClan Name: $clubname";
        $headers = "From: your_email@example.com";

        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "<p>Email sent successfully</p>";
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_form_submission');



Breaks Code: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
I have tried this but not working.  it removes the css completely.

if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        global $post;
        if ($post->ID == 7293) {
            ?>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <?php
        } else {

        }
    }
}


So I did find a solution.  Another plugin that i can add the css to the head on that page edit only.  I still would like to know a way to do this without a plugin though.

Don't inject JS or CSS directly like this; use WordPress's enqueuing system instead.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse425304_add_css' );
function wpse425304_add_css() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'bootstrap',
    'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'  
  );
}

References

wp_enqueue_scripts hook
wp_enqueue_style()


Thank you.  This cleared it up.
